# How to append value to a cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I am creating a new column and populating its value. Based on the condition, the new column needs to have some values appended to it if that row is encountered again.

So for example for a given dataframe:

df

```
id   Stores                  is_open
1   'Walmart', 'Target'      true
2   'Best Buy'               false
3   'Target'                 true
4   'Home Depot'             true
```

Now If I want to add a new column as a `Ticker` that can be a comma-separated string of tickers or list (whichever is preferable and easier. No preference on my end) for the given comma separated stores.

So for example ticker of Walmart is `wmt` and target is `tgt`. The `wmt` and `tgt` data I am getting from another dataframe based on matching key so I tried to add as follows but not all of them are assigned even though they have values and only one value followed by a comma is assigned to `Tickers` column and not multiple:

```
df['Tickers'] = '' 
for _, row in df.iterrows():
        stores = row['Stores']
        list_stores = stores(',')
        if len(list_stores) > 1:
            for store in list_stores:
                tmp_df = second_df[second_df['store_id'] == store]

                ticker = tmp_df['Ticker'].values[0] if len(tmp_df['Ticker'].values) > 0 else None

                if ticker:
                    df.loc[
                      df['Stores'].astype(str).str.contains(store), 'Ticker'] += '{},'.format(ticker)
```

Expected output:

```
id   Stores                  is_open      Ticker
1   'Walmart', 'Target'      true         wmt, tgt
2   'Best Buy'               false        bby
3   'Target'                 true         tgt
4   'Home Depot'             true         nan
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar added. Please check my edits

Comment: Can you add `second_df`? What's type of `Stores` column ?

Comment: do you have a dictionary of tickers with the actual name as keys? or if you can post the df containing tickers tht would be great. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method with `axis=1` to pass the row and perform your calculations. See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = {'id':[1,2],'Store':["'Walmart','Target'","'Best Buy'"], 'is_open':['true', 'false']}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict, index=[0,1])
df.set_index('id',drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The `df` so far:

```
                 Store is_open
id                            
1   'Walmart','Target'    true
2           'Best Buy'   false
```

The lookup dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Store':['Walmart', 'Target','Best Buy'], 'Ticker':['wmt','tgt','bby']})
```

```
      Store Ticker
0   Walmart    wmt
1    Target    tgt
2  Best Buy    bby
```

here is the code for adding the column:

```
def add_column(row):

    items = row['Store'].split(',')

    tkr_list = []

    for string in items:
        mystr = string.replace("'","")

        tkr = df2.loc[df2['Store']==mystr,'Ticker'].values[0]

        tkr_list.append(tkr)

    return tkr_list


df['Ticker']=df.apply(add_column, axis=1)
```

and this is the result for `df`:

```
                 Store is_open      Ticker
id                                        
1   'Walmart','Target'    true  [wmt, tgt]
2           'Best Buy'   false       [bby]
```